# Pivot table in pandas then convert to json table

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is the code for the table I am starting with.

```
data = [['tom', 'class a', 20], ['nick', 'class a', 14], 
['juli','class b', 14],['jane','class b', 155],['jone','class c', 80]]
  

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'class', 'grade'])
```

| Name | class | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | class a | 20 |
| nick | class a | 14 |
| juli | class b | 14 |
| jane | class b | 155 |
| jone | class c | 80 |

I tried to pivot it using:

```
 df = pd.pivot_table(
        data=df,
        index='class',
        columns = 'Name',
        values = 'grade' )
    
 df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
 df = df.rename(columns ={'class':'class'}) 
 s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) 
 df = df.set_index(s)
```

And then turning it into a json table using:

```
df = json.dumps(df.to_dict())
```

I am getting this in the end:

```
{
    "class": {"1": "class a", "2": "class b", "3": "class c"},
    "jane": {"1": NaN, "2": 155.0, "3": NaN},
    "jone": {"1": NaN, "2": NaN, "3": 80.0},
    "juli": {"1": NaN, "2": 14.0, "3": NaN},
    "tom": {"1": 20.0, "2": NaN, "3": NaN},
}
```

While the intended result would be something like this:

```
{
  "class": class a,
  "tom": 20,
  "nick": 14,
  "juli": 0,
  "jane": 0 or NaN doesnt matter,
  "jone": 0 or NaN
}, {
  "class": class b,
  "tom": 0 or NaN,
  "nick": 0 or NaN,
  "juli": 14,
  "jane": 155,
  "jone": 0 or NaN
}, {
  "class": class c,
  "tom": 0 or NaN,
  "nick": 0 or NaN,
  "juli": 0 or NaN,
  "jane": 0 or NaN,
  "jone": 80
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `orient=` argument on the `to_dict()` call? For example `orient='records'` or `orient='index'`? See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: Also, there is a purpose-built [to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) function that could reduce the steps you need to take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.to_dict("records")`. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Output:

```
[{'class': 'class a', 'jane': nan, 'jone': nan, 'juli': nan, 'nick': 14.0, 'tom': 20.0}, {'class': 'class b', 'jane': 155.0, 'jone': nan, 'juli': 14.0, 'nick': nan, 'tom': nan}, {'class': 'class c', 'jane': nan, 'jone': 80.0, 'juli': nan, 'nick': nan, 'tom': nan}]
```

Additionally, renaming class to class is redundant